# how to edit XML data within SOAP Request using C#?

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I would like to edit xml data for one element with in SOAP request in order to send unique SOAP requests.

Following is the example request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:web="http://webservice/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:ca>
         <type1>
            <ad>2013-07-19</ad>
            <name>abcd 13071502</name>
            <taker>
               <taker>TEST</taker>
               <emailAddress>test@test.com</emailAddress>
               <name>nameTest</name>
               <phoneNo>007007007</phoneNo>
               <takerUid>1234</takerUid>
            </taker>
         </type1>
         <type2>4</type2>
         <type3>peace</type3>
         <type4>test</type4>
      </web:ca>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I would like to change "name" element value from "abcd 13071502" to "abcd ".  I was able to extract data from "name" element and edit the value by using following code in C#

```
System.Xml.XmlTextReader xr = new XmlTextReader(@filePath);
while (xr.Read())
{
if (xr.LocalName == "name")
    {
        xr.Read();
        currentNameValue = xr.Value;
        int cnvLen = currentNameValue.Length;
        string cnvWOdate = currentNameValue.Substring(0, cnvLen-8);
        string newNameValue = cnvWOdate+currTimeDate;
        break;
    }
}
```

However, I couldn't figure out how to edit the value and save the file. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: FYI, `new XmlTextReader()` has been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `XmlDocument` class instead of the `XmlTextReader` class.

```
System.Xml.XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.Load(@"filepath");

foreach(XmlNode nameNode in xd.GetElementsByTagName("name"))
{
    if(nameNode.ParentNode.Name == "type1")
    {
        string currentNameValue = nameNode.InnerText;
        int cnvLen = currentNameValue.Length;
        string cnvWOdate = currentNameValue.Substring(0,cnvLen-8);
        string newNameValue = cnvWOdate+currTimeDate;

        nameNode.InnerText = newNameValue;
    }
}

xd.Save(@"newFilePath");
```

Comment: Thanks for Quick response. But for some reason (as I struggled earlier), this code is not recognizing "name" element. I have received "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error message.

Comment: Sounds like a `NullReferenceException`. Which line is this happening on?

Comment: I believe this is happening right after currentNameValue = nameNode.InnerText;

Comment: HI Nicholas, Just to remind you there are two tags with same name as "name", is this causing problem ?

Comment: I have made a few corrections and have tested this code. Apart from not having the string `currTimeDate` defined in my version, it runs fine and performs as expected.

Comment: I'm afraid, still receiving _null_ for _currentNameValue_

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? I am not sure how the `InnerText` property can be null, as when I test it with an XML element `<name />` the `InnerText` property is an empty string, not null. The posted code works with the posted XML. I suspect your SOAP response is different than the sample you posted.

Comment: Hi Nicholas, it may sound stupid, I have given `filepath` in wrong format (`C:\filename.xml`) and that's why it is returning `null`. Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("file path");

XmlNode nameNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Envelope/Body/ca/type1/name");

string currentNameValue = nameNode != null ? nameNode.InnerText : "name not exist";
int cnvLen = currentNameValue.Length;
string cnvWOdate = currentNameValue.Substring(0, cnvLen-8);
string newNameValue = cnvWOdate+currTimeDate;

nameNode.InnerText = newNameValue; //set new value to tag
```

To get `Value` or `InnerText` of a node, you will have to make sure the node exist. The line `string currentNameValue` has the format like this:

```
var variable = condition ? A : B;
```

It's basically saying that if condition is true, then variable equals A, otherwise, variable equals B.

Comment: Performing the null check is a good approach if you are calling `SelectSingleNode`. However, I disagree with your use of a default value "name not exist" because the rest of the code will continue to execute and will produce odd results. It is probably better to wrap the `InnerText` modification in an `if` block. My answer avoids this since the `foreach` loop will only iterate when the node is not null anyway.

Comment: @nicholas right, the foreach loop will only iterate the ones that are not null. However, he said that he is still getting null reference, so I suspect that the null reference is from somewhere else, that why I suggest checking the specific ones. And with the default value, "name not exist" is just a suggestion, he can even assign as empty string and check later. But yes, I agree there are multiple ways to attack this problem.

Comment: @sora0419 - Thanks for your answer, I have found why I am getting `null` reference as I given as I have given wrong format in filepath. For my problem, I can vote your answer as acceptable too; unfortunately, this forum gives me option to choose only one.